# Redirect to subdomain port 8080

Tags: apache, redirects, vps, tomcat

I have my domain registered and running. I have installed lifray which is running on tomcat 7, my site url is iloveliferay.com:8080 and I want this to be at `themes.iloveliferay.com`, which file I need to change to make this possible?

I have VM cloude hosting and I have root access.

Comment: What you need to do is set apache to act as a proxy for your main domain and forward requests locally to the tomcat server. It may be better to ask this question on serverfault.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look at the info provided here :

http://www.servletworld.com/tomcat/howto-change-tomcat-port.html

(Essential content inserted here as that link is down in Feb 2013.)
Look for the section in server.xml like this and change the port to 80.

```
<connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
                  connectiontimeout="20000" 
                  redirectport="8443"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit on http.conf

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80>
    ServerName mail.domain.com
    RedirectPermanent / http://domain.com:port 
</VirtualHost>
```